# is there any way to trigger a method when users mouse over the Title of a column in GWT-CellTable?

Tags: gwt

Ok, I have a CellTable `CellTable<List<String>> table = new CellTable<List<String>>();`

& a nameColumn `IndexedColumn nameColumn=new IndexedColumn(0)`

then  `table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");`

I want that when user `mouseOver` the title of `nameColumn` it will trigger `methodX`

The `table.addCellPreviewHandler` only works for the cell inside the table not for the Title or header of the column

```
table.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<List<String>>(){

        @Override
        public void onCellPreview(
                        CellPreviewEvent<List<String>> event) {

        if ("mouseover".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
                        int col=event.getColumn();
                        int row=event.getIndex();
        //call sthing here
        }
});
```

is there any simple method like `table.addCellPreviewHandler`  that help me to solve my problem?
I don't like custom Header or custom column?

I tried:

```
Header<String> nameColumnHeader = new Header<String>(new ClickableTextCell()) {
        @Override
        public String getValue() {
            return "Name";
        }

        @Override
        public final void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem, NativeEvent event) {
         if ("mouseover".equals(event.getType())) {
           //
           meaningMessagesPopup.show();  
         }
         else if("mouseout".equals(event.getType())){
             meaningMessagesPopup.hide();
         }
        }
    };
table.addColumn(nameColumn, nameColumnHeader);
```

But seem Gwt did not recognize `"mouseover".equals(event.getType())`

Answer (score 0):

All of us have had problems with "widgets" and events sometimes, so do not worry.

The problem is ClickableTextCell only has sunk events for "`click`" and "`keydown`", so  it does not listen for anymore.

Normally in widgets you can specify more events using the method `sinkEvents`, but in that case that method does not exist.

From my opinion I think the easiest solution is create your own "`ClickableTextCell`". I have done it, and works like a charm:

```
import static com.google.gwt.dom.client.BrowserEvents.CLICK;
import static com.google.gwt.dom.client.BrowserEvents.KEYDOWN;
import static com.google.gwt.dom.client.BrowserEvents.MOUSEOUT;
import static com.google.gwt.dom.client.BrowserEvents.MOUSEOVER;

import com.google.gwt.cell.client.AbstractSafeHtmlCell;
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context;
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.ValueUpdater;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlBuilder;
import com.google.gwt.text.shared.SafeHtmlRenderer;
import com.google.gwt.text.shared.SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer;


public abstract class MyClickableTextCell extends AbstractSafeHtmlCell<String> {

  /**
   * Construct a new ClickableTextCell that will use a
   * {@link SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer}.
   */
  public MyClickableTextCell() {
    this(SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer.getInstance());
  }

  /**
   * Construct a new ClickableTextCell that will use a given
   * {@link SafeHtmlRenderer}.
   * 
   * @param renderer a {@link SafeHtmlRenderer SafeHtmlRenderer<String>} instance
   */
  public MyClickableTextCell(SafeHtmlRenderer<String> renderer) {
    super(renderer, CLICK, KEYDOWN, MOUSEOVER, MOUSEOUT);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value,
      NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    if (CLICK.equals(event.getType())) {
      onEnterKeyDown(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    }
    if (CLICK.equals(event.getType())) {
      onEnterKeyDown(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    }
    if (MOUSEOVER.equals(event.getType())) {
      onMouseOver(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    }
    if (MOUSEOUT.equals(event.getType())) {
      onMouseOut(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    }
  }

  public abstract void onMouseOver(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, Element parent,
      String value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater);

  public abstract void onMouseOut(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, Element parent,
      String value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater);

  @Override
  protected void onEnterKeyDown(Context context, Element parent, String value,
      NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
    if (valueUpdater != null) {
      valueUpdater.update(value);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void render(Context context, SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    if (value != null) {
      sb.append(value);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see there are two abstract methods that you need to fill when you create the object. Those methods are when the onMouseOver and onMouseOut are fired.

So basically, when you create your `Header<String> nameColumnHeader`, you should do something like:

```
    MyClickableTextCell cl = new MyClickableTextCell() {

      @Override
      public void onMouseOver(Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event,
          ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
        GQuery.console.log("onMouseOver");
      }

      @Override
      public void onMouseOut(Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event,
          ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
        GQuery.console.log("onMouseOut");        
      }
    };

  //Specify the MyClickableTextCell to you Column's Header  
  Header<String> nameColumnHeader = new Header<String>(cl){
      ....
  }

  .... //Add the Column with the Header to the CellTable as normal.
```

Happy coding!

Comment: thax you, i will test your solution

Comment: Have you tried it? I am curious if it worked or you find another workaround. Thanks!